# Output only certain values from nvarchar column using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, nvarchar

I have a SQL database that's filled with all kind of logging information, including full Description of Windows Event Logs. This Description is a nvarchar column which consists of information that looks like this:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-18
    Account Name:       XXX-XXX01$
    Account Domain:     XXX
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         8

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       username
    Account Domain:     domain

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x1111
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   XXX-XXX04
    Source Network Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I would like to only retrieve the values after "Account Name:" and "Account Domain:" under "Account For Which Logon Failed:" using a select statement so I can use that in Excel and/or Power BI.

Is this possible?

Comment: Show screenshoot from database please , how your data looks like in table. It's like string?

Comment: No, don't follow @Adamszsz advice here, an image of text is never helpful. DDL and DML statements are *way* better. But if you want to consume Windows Logs, SQL server is the completely wrong tool. There are most certainly tools out there that can, and very likely some of them can insert that data into SQL Server in a **consumable** format.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. As Larnu stated, this is definitely not the ideal way to do it, especially if you're looking at a lot of data. But if you're only consuming within the hundreds or low thousands, that's not too taxing. You'll likely want to use a combination of `CHARINDEX()` AND `SUBSTRING()` to get what you want.

Comment: @Larnu the database is filled by a monitoring agent, I don't have any control on where the information is saved. However I need this information for certain compliance aspects where we need to monitor on failed access for example and this database is the only information store that has this information and for all systems involved.

Comment: If its for compliance, then I would suggest that would make it much easier to get the budget for the correct tool to do this. Legal requirements often are the easiest way for a company to open it wallet.

Comment: @HendrikJohanWagenaar so what does your example shoe? Is this one value / one record? Or are there numerous records to stroe this info?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: If you can pull the event log as XML (the way it is actually stored) that will be much easier as you can use XQuery

Answer (score 0):

I guess the provided sample is the content og one column / one string. In this case I would suggest to use a combination of `charindex` and `xml.nodes`.

Following an example:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(max) = 'An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-18
    Account Name:       XXX-XXX01$
    Account Domain:     XXX
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         8

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       username
    Account Domain:     domain

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x1111
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   XXX-XXX04
    Source Network Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX';


DECLARE @idxLogonFailed bigint = charindex('Account For Which Logon Failed:'+char(13)+char(10), @x);
DECLARE @idxFailureInfo bigint = charindex('Failure Information:'+char(13)+char(10), @x);
DECLARE @logonFailedLen int = @idxFailureInfo-@idxLogonFailed;

DECLARE @logonFailedSubstr NVARCHAR(1000) = SUBSTRING(@x, @idxLogonFailed, @logonFailedLen);
DECLARE @newLineIdx INT = charindex(char(13)+char(10), @logonFailedSubstr);

DECLARE @xXml xml = CAST(REPLACE('<a><b>' + REPLACE(@logonFailedSubstr, char(13)+char(10), '</b><b>') + '</b></a>', '<b></b>', '') AS XML);

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT TRIM(T.r.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)')) AS x
    FROM @xXml.nodes('/a/b') as T(r)
),
cteSplit AS(
  SELECT *, TRIM(LEFT(x, CHARINDEX(':', x)-1)) AS description, TRIM(RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-CHARINDEX(':', x))) AS val
    FROM cte
    WHERE CHARINDEX(':', x) > -1
)
SELECT description, val
  FROM cteSplit
  WHERE description IN ('Account Name','Account Domain')
```